# Asking answers only from BORI edition of Mahabharata

Tags: discussion, answers, asking-questions

I see a few questions which demand answer only from the [BORI Critical Edition of Mahabharata (MBH)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhandarkar_Oriental_Research_Institute#The_Critical_Edition_of_the_Mahabharata). Now if someone has studied the popular, not critically edited version of MBH (e.g., K M Ganguli's translation available at [sacred-texts.com](https://sacred-texts.com/hin/maha/index.htm)) but they aren't sure what's included in the BORI CE or not, should they waste their time in just figuring out if a particular story is present in BORI CE or not?

Answer (score 3):

IMO, if the ask is from a particular version, then the answer should be posted as per that version only.

> should he waste his/her time in just figuring out if that particular part present in BORI or not?

Totally upto the user, if they can invest some time to read the asked version, they can do or else some other user who already has studied the version, will post the answer.

Comment: That means a qualified user would be treated as disqualified... :(

Comment: Nobody is perfect, don't bother @YDS :D

Comment: I second that answer from @TheLittleNaruto.  Nothing wrong if a user wants to check BORI edition and provide answers. Waste or not depends on the individual who chooses (or not) to spend the time. Alternatively a user can refrain from posting answers - either because he or she doesn't have access to BORI edition, or doesnt prefer to do it, or for any reason that may apply to an individual. But what I would suggest is, if the question is specific to BORI edition, then it is ideal any answers provided are based on the BORI edition. That will help avoid confusion and misunderstanding.

Answer (score 2):

> Should they **waste their time** in figuring out if a particular story is present in BORI CE or not?

No they shouldn't. We have to remember that this is a Q & A site. If OP is already aware of the popular version of the story from MBH but sees some discrepancies in it and wants to know how the CE team dealt with them, why do you want waste your energy telling them what they already know?

If you don't like BORI CE for some reason it's really easy to walk away from such questions. Downvote if you don't like them. But we shouldn't be trying to close such questions as has been done with *[Is the Virata war an interpolation according to BORI scholars?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/31466/is-the-virata-war-an-interpolation-according-to-bori-scholars)*

Also, suggest you read the post [Closing Questions That Raise Issues You Disagree With](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94/closing-questions-that-raise-issues-you-disagree-with) from Parenting Meta. When it comes to answering any question on any SE site, it's best to put yourself in OP's shoes, then proceed to answer. If you cannot do that, it's best to leave it to those who are willing to do it.

Comment: The linked Q is a different one...in this OP doesn't want answer even from BORI CE, see his comment on the answer...he wanted answer from BORI scholars studies..

Comment: Still, it is connected with Hinduism, how is it off-topic? It seemed like some users didn't like the question so closed it. "I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because user doesn't want answer from scriptures." - so other questions like [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/3373/were-hindu-scriptures-tampered-with-by-the-british) are also off-topic because they can't be answered using scripture?